# storage file path issue it repeat on serer side

Tags: laravel

My issue is simple but critical as well. The problem is asset function created different paths for local and staging. On local it creates perfect path but on server it creates incorrect one. On local it creates

> http://localhost/storage/images/img.png

but on server it creates

> http://domain/storage/images/storage/images/img.png

why its repeating `storage/images` 2 times on server.

```
    <a class="start-stream open">
        <span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span>

        <div class="text">Create Session</div>
    </a>

    @foreach($areaOfInterest as $interest) @php $str2 = parse_url($interest->image) @endphp

    <a href="{{url('all-streams/'.$interest->slug)}}" class="ovelay-text stream-cat" style="background-image: url('{{ asset(storage/images/$str2['path']) }}');">{{$interest->name}}</a> @endforeach

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
{{ asset('images/' . $str2['path']) }}
```

I assume you created symlink from storage to public on your server

Comment: can i differentiate b/w local and server so when local the path is like this and when server it become like that. is it any way to do this?

Comment: I would keep the same approach for both local and production. Keep images in storage but serve them from public by creating a symlink.

Comment: yup. you are right.but this is a existing project and previously the path that save it db is public/images and my approach is to just save the file name and when retrieve it just concatenate 'storage/directory-name'.$var is it right approach?